# how to create integratable module for mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, hybrid-mobile-app

Let's say I want to build a mobile App which others can include/integrate in their app as a separtate module. The goal is that the customers can add the functinality of my app into theirs. Since the customers have different OS/plattforms it should be plattform independent. Could i write a html5 hybrid app which is then integratable through a plugin into every existing app?

Comment: What do you want your plugin to be able to do?

Comment: Its sort of a standardized form(checkboxes, textfields..) with some native features like accessing the camera, location. It also includes drawing and drag & drop features which are built using the touch-events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact that you want to use native features and want developers to actually integrate your plugin you likely do best by programming it natively.