# How to write a "module" for extending existing mobile apps?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, xamarin, mobile-application

This is probably a duplicate of [how to create integratable module for mobile apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019100/how-to-create-integratable-module-for-mobile-apps) - but that question is over 3 years old and I'll try to be more specific.

I want to create a sort of "online store" app (ideally one that can access beacons) and sell it to different companies as a white-label product (so they can brand it the way they like it). The thing here is that most customers will already have a mobile app of their own and it seems likely that they'll say downloading another app would be too much hassle for their customers, especially since they have other revenue-generating features in their own app.
So the question is, what would be a good way to create such a "plug-in module" that they can simply include in their existing app?
Requiring them to recompile/publish their own app would probably be a smaller hurdle than a second, independent app.

I know some apps simply load a mobile website to integrate third-party feature (like an IFRAME), but I'm not a fan of that as it's usually very slow since the page takes time to load.

If their is no "one-size fits all" solution, I would be fine with maintaining separate versions of my "app" module for Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a SaaS solution:

- You need to create a library. The library can be added to the existing app. You have to expose an API so the library can be started from the existing app.
- You need a dashboard for each client can access their account and input configuration values, colors, products, prices, etc. Also here either a super admin like a developer must configure the payment services keys, this can be done by the store developer or as part of your service.
- You need a backend to handle business logic like matching admin accounts to the correct data, permissions for CRUD and very important serve the configurations to the app and make the payments secure.

The library will need some configurations values, so you could make it to automatically look for a JSON file with a specific name, that file could be downloaded from the dashboard. That file would contain things as api keys to match the store data. The library will make an HTTP request using the API key to retrieve the needed values, colors, products, etc. This way colors and products can be dynamic. The store API key can be public because is a public request, app users need to see the colors and products. The key is used in the backend for knowing which data response.

Your library will be basically a list of products that are obtained from the HTTP request, and the colors can be set programmatically as well. The critic complexity is to make your library able to make the HTTP requests to GET the data to show in the app and to POST the payments to the backend.

The backend must make sure the payments are secure and the buyer's payment is transfer correctly to the store owner. Therefore besides provisioning both clients, the web dashboard and the Android app with data, it has to include the payment services SDKs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not sure if I worded my question very well. My question was how to build a GUI (!) module/library that can be integrated into more or less any existing app (iOS or Android). I'm not sure if you answered that question? Backend logic etc. is not an issue at all. The question is how to build a GUI/dialog that they can just add to their app without loading an external website (since that is much slower than an app dialog). Maybe I can do it as an HTML5 app, but somehow include the frontend in the app?